# Spring Boot Servlet 4 support

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-webflux, servlet-4

Which version of Spring Boot will (or does) officially support Servlet 4 spec?  Where can one see the new features that come with it documented?

Thank you.

Comment: Spring Boot 2.0 (which isn't final yet). That supports Spring Framework 5.x which has been upgraded to use the Servlet 4.0 spec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Framework 5 supports the Servlet 4 spec (see [SPR-12674](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12674)).
Not a lot of new features related to that, really. You can now inject a `PushBuilder` as a controller method argument **if it is available** (HTTP/2 enabled, supported by the client, etc).

Note that you need to use a Servlet 4 based container to use those features (see [SPR-15593](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-15593)), or you'll need to fall back on container specific APIs which have been available for quite a while now.

Spring Framework does the job here, so there isn't anything special scheduled for now in Spring Boot 2.0; don't hesitate to open enhancement requests [on the dedicated issue tracker](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues) if you've got ideas.